# GitLab multiple if clauses based on files changes condition within a single job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

This surely have a lot of application, but here is a simple example:

I want to auto-increment version in `package.json` based on what part of app is updated:

So lets say our package.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "serverVersion": "0.1.2",
  "clientVersion": "1.2.3",
...
}
```

and app structure is:

```
app/
├── server
│   ├── 
│   └── 
├── client
│   ├── 
│   └── 
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
└── package.json
```

Ideally, within a single job I should be able to run multiple if clauses, based on what files changed, such as:

```yaml
main:
  rules:
    - if:
      changes:
        - app/server/**/*
      script:
        - echo do something for server here
    - if:
      changes:
        - app/server/**/*
      script:
        - echo do something for client here
```

or maybe at least allow to operate this clause using variables:

```yaml
main:
  variables:
    VARIABLE_CLIENT: 'false'
    VARIABLE_SERVER: 'false'
  rules:
    - if:
      changes:
        - apps/server/**/*
      variables:
        VARIABLE_SERVER: 'true'
    - if: 
      changes:
        - apps/client/**/*
      variables:
        VARIABLE_CLIENT: 'true'
  script:
    - if $VARIABLE_SERVER == 'true'; then
        echo do something for server here
      fi
    - if $VARIABLE_CLIENT == 'true'; then
        echo do something for client here
      fi
```

but unfortunately, non of this is possible.

All the pieces are there, but you cannot use them together.

Is there a way to handle this scenarios, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible, but not the way you currently have it.

The `rules` in a GitLab CI pipeline are a set of conditions to determine if a job *should be added to any given pipeline instance*. Otherwise, they have no function.

Knowing this, we can adapt your first example by splitting your two use cases into two jobs: one for changes to the server, and one for changes to the client:

```yaml
server_job:
  rules:
    - if:
      changes:
        - app/server/**/*
  script:
    - echo do something for server here

client_job:
  rules:
    - if:
      changes:
        - app/client/**/*
  script:
    - echo do something for client here
```

With these jobs, if a commit/tag is pushed (or other pipeline triggers based on the [`$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)) with changes to the `app/server/*` directory, the `server_job` will be added to the pipeline, and the `client_job` will not. You won't even see it in the pipeline diagram -- it won't exist. The opposite is also true if there are changes to only `app/client/*`, and if there are changes to both directories, both jobs will be added to the pipeline.

The most important thing to know about the `rules`, `workflow`, `only`, and `except` keywords is that they're evaluated before any jobs run. For more information about `rules` is available [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules).

Comment: Thank you Adam for your answer, however emphasis in this question is a multiple clause **within a single job**.

Comment: Yep, understood, but you cannot do exactly what you want in a single job. Since any and all rules only determine if that specific job will be added to the pipeline, you cannot "run this script for this rule or that job for that rule". If you have multiple conditions that determine if a single job that does a single thing should be run, one job is of course fine. But if you have different things that happen based on your rules, they must be separate jobs.

Comment: Yes, that is what appears to be the case. 
In my question, I was playing with clause based on what git files were updated, and I was able to set bypass GitLab limitations using git cli, simply pulling list of files:

Comment: Yes, that is always another option. If the `rules` are too stringent for what you're looking to do, you can always implement it manually in your `script` (or `before_script`) and then either `exit` to not run the job or run one script or another like you're looking to do.

Comment: Yes, that is what appears to be the case. 
In my question, I was playing with clause based on what git files were updated, and I was able to set bypass GitLab limitations using git cli, simply pulling list of files, checking if file/folder that I'm looking for is in the list and setting a VAR that is utilized in the if statement in the next line:
```bash
 - git whatchanged origin/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH -n 1 | grep '/client' > /dev/null 2>&1 && CLIENT_UPD=true
 - >
if [[ -z ${CLIENT_UPD} ]]; then
        echo Hi
      fi
```
...but it would be neat to have this as a part of gitlab CLI =)

Comment: Sorry, couldn't edit my answer fast enough. 
Agree. Thanks Adam

Comment: Yeah, there could be some improvements or more options. If you're interested, you can [submit an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/new), and if you're a paid subscriber you can talk to support as it will receive more weight.